# Download Full HD YouTube video in python

Tags: python, download, youtube

I want to download a video from youtube's url. I used pytube but it only downloaded low resolution video or high resolution no audio. How to download a high resolution video with audio from youtube in python? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are talking about this, referenced here: **https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html**

"You may notice that some streams listed have both a video codec and audio codec, while others have just video or just audio, this is a result of YouTube supporting a streaming technique called Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH).

In the context of pytube, the implications are for the highest quality streams; you now need to download both the audio and video tracks and then post-process them with software like FFmpeg to merge them.

The legacy streams that contain the audio and video in a single file (referred to as “progressive download”) are still available, but only for resolutions 720p and below."

Answer (score 4):

```
import pytube
link = "put yur link url here" 
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
stream.download()
```

When you code `yt.streams.first()` you don't get the highest resolution just try to change it to get highest resolution

Answer (score 1):

pytube does not support streams higher than 720p and also does not support 720p 60fps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I made a downloader because of this problem. With my downloader you can download 1080p videos with audio. You can take a look to my GitHub Page: https://github.com/ArdaArslann/Youtube-1080p-with-Audio-Video-Downloader/blob/master/p.py